# using export in alloy controller versus attaching functions directly to the '$' scope

Tags: titanium-alloy, commonjs

here is the code of an alloy controller written in two different ways. Although the both work the same, Which one might be best practice?

example 1 of controller.js:

```
var currentState = true;
$.getState = function(){
    return currentState;
}
```

example 2 of controller.js:

```
var currentState = true;
exports.getState = function(){
    return currentState;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Titanium is based on the CommonJS framework. The exports variable is a special variable used typically to expose a public API in a class object. So when you want to expose a method of doSomething() on the MyModule.js class you would use the exports variable like this:

```
exports.doSomething() = function(args) {
  //Some really cool method here
};
```

Then reference that class using

```
var myModule = require('MyModule');
myModule.doSomething();
```

However when referencing a view object the typical way to reference the is using the $. shortcut. You can see they prefer that method in the official documentation.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_XML_Markup

Answer (score 0):

The `$` variable holds a reference to your controller instance. It also contains some references to all indexed views (understand, views for which you supplied an index in you xml markup).

Both ways are **strictly equivalent** as, during the compilation, Alloy will merge the content of the `exports` with your controller referenced in   `$`.  Adding them directly to the instance won't change a thing.

Neverthless, developers are used to see the public API as the set of functions exported via the special variable `exports`; Thus, I will recommend to keep using it in a clean and clear way (for instance, defining your functions in your module scope, and only expose them at the end or beginning of your controller).

```
function myFunction1 () { }
function myFunction2 () { }
function myFunction3 () { }


exports.myFunction1 = myFunction1;
exports.myFunction3 = myFunction3;
```

Thereby, your API is quite clear for people diving into your source code. (A readMe file is also highly recommended :) ).